# GWT SuggestBox custom non-text editor

Tags: gwt

In my application I've got about a dozen places where I need to show a country suggest box. All the code of the suggest box(including the creation of a custom `SuggestOracle`, it's initialization and various handlers) take up some ~100 lines of and copying it all over the project seems quite hardcore for me.
So I decided to write a custom `CountrySuggestBox` which extended `SuggestBox` wrapped in itself the construction of my custom `SuggestOracle` and did all the click/key handling stuff in itself. After this I was planning to just write something in the lines of `@UiFiled(provided=true) CountrySuggestBox = new CountrySuggestBox(countryList);` and be done with it. But for that I also need CountrySuggestBox to implement `LeafValueEditor<Country>` which i can't do cause SuggestBox implements HasText and these interfaces do not "like" each other.

So how can I make `CountrySuggestBox` an  editor of country types property without writing custom editor methods in the classes using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prefer composition over inheritance.**

Have `CountrySuggestBox` extend `Composite` (or simply implement `IsWidget`) and wrap the `SuggestBox`. 
Then you can make it a `LeafValueEditor<Country>` or `IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<Country>>` (along with `TakesValue<Country>` or `HasValue<Country>`)